# Uncaught Reference Error: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on an app for webOS that will take a megaupload link(assuming its a video), parse it into a direct link and stream it to a ffplay port for webos called TouchPlay.
I'm working on a basic prototype that will just take the end code on a megaupload link and return a direct link.
Now that I have laid out the basic parts of my application, on to my question.  I want to take data in a form in an html page and feed it into a function in an external js script.
Here's the html portion

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="source/main.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
            Enter the MegaUpload Code, ex. megaupload.com/?d=glgrn8f1 -> glgrn8f1: <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="">
            <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Click" onClick="javascript:codeIn(this.form);">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And in my main.js file is in a subdirectory called source and it contains `function codeIn(code){` plus the rest of the functions.

Yet when I enter some test data in my web page and hit submit, I get an error in the chrome dev console saying `Uncaught Reference Error: codeIn is not defined`

I have a very limited experience with html and javascript, but I cant seem to figure this out, I imagine its something really simple that I'm missing.

EDIT:  Here's main.js, and yes, I have checked for typos. Just ask if you need to see the contents of any of these functions, but I didn't think they were neccesary.

```
function codeIn(code){
    ...
}

function getInfo(url){
    ...
}

function waiting(timer){
...

}
```

Ive looked through all these suggestions and it all seems to point to a syntax error, yet when I try to put all the js functions into the head of the html, it works.  So thats what I'm doing.  I don't change a single thing when I reference it from source/main.js, but whatever.

Comment: How is your codeIn function declared in main.js? Also, you shouldn't use the `language` attribute. It has been deprecated. `type="text/javascript"` should be used instead.

Comment: Off-topic: As a good practice, you should enter HTML tags and attributes all-lowercase. It is not a requirement for HTML (though it is for XHTML - XML is case-sensitive), but sticking to conventions is good and makes your code more readable. So change to `<input type="button" ... value="Click" ... >`.

Comment: The cause of the error might be syntax error in `codeIn` definition. Show us that code. To self-debug, place `alert("foo");` before and after `codeIn` definition (or better, use Firebug and `console.log(...)`). If alert is executed only once, you have syntax error. The trivial cause might be that main.js is not in source folder (typo?) but I hope you've checked that.

Comment: +1 for error in `main.js`. Per [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P23uz/), if your `main.js` has no errors then your code will run just fine, so it must be something in the javascript file.

Comment: are you familiar with tools like firebug??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the look of it, I think you then need to double check the location of `main.js`. Verify whether your HTML file is in a location from where main.js can be accessed as `source/main.js`, rather than something like `../source/main.js` (in case your HTML file is in a folder parallel/sibling to the `source` folder)

Answer (score 1):

The RefereceError in general related to the scope of function that is present and the function call that is being made. It might the source path of the js, html/xhtml/jsp or function scope with in the js file. Hope this helps. Thanks.